# inheriting the methods of a control in usercontrol

Tags: c#

I developing a usercontrol in csharp in which i will be using a textbox and CheckedListBox control once the usercontrol is done suppose if i want to use some of the methods of Checkedlistbox in my usercontrol what should i do...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just encapsulate them in their own method and delegate calls to them.

If one of the user controls is defined as the field `chkListBox`, and you want to use the `ClearSelected` method you can do the following in your class:

```
public void ClearSelected()
{
   chkListBox.ClearSelected();
}
```